# fullcalendar - How to fixed width resource column and horizontal scrolling

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar with resourceDay being included in (from plnkr.co/KRXcK2oNd9eX2IMBM6yY)

Is there any way to fixed width of resources column?

I want to fixed width of each resource and can be scroll resources horizontally

Comment: Did you find anything on this issue?I want to implement the same.

Comment: @SauravDangol No, I did not