# How to fixed width of resources column in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

in the same situation
[fullcalendar - How to fixed width resource column and horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518337)

but i haven't found answer.
Is there any way to fixed width of resources column?

please see the below picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGsni.png)

Comment: Could you write an example of what you have, like is done [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5203), see [this](https://codepen.io/Stalyon-Pwi/pen/ZEYaXVJ)

Comment: why is it important to fix the widths of the resource columns? Surely that just makes your page less responsive to changes in the user's screen size?

Comment: I'll create many column. the context lenth in columns are not sure.(some fields just show icon, some fields show many content.)
Now user must adjustment border of table everytime. So I want default column width.